# in python3, how to split lists of list at a specific position?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, split

```
['2006/10/18 21:15:51 4.823 -82.592 37.3 SOUTH OF PANAMA']  
['2006/10/18 10:08:45 32.165 -115.891 7.3 BAJA CALIFORNIA, MEXICO']
```

There are two lists from the same original list:

```
a = [['2006/10/18 21:15:51 4.823 -82.592 37.3 SOUTH OF PANAMA'], 
['2006/10/18 10:08:45 32.165 -115.891 7.3 BAJA CALIFORNIA, MEXICO'] ]
```

Here I want to split each of them before the country names, like:

```
['2006/10/18 21:15:51 4.823 -82.592 37.3]' '[SOUTH OF PANAMA']  
['2006/10/18 10:08:45 32.165 -115.891 7.3]' '[BAJA CALIFORNIA, MEXICO']
```

my problem is how to use split() (or maybe some other ways) to let python understand I want to separate these lists at this specific position?

Comment: You want to split strings, not lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = [['2006/10/18 21:15:51 4.823 -82.592 37.3 SOUTH OF PANAMA'], 
['2006/10/18 10:08:45 32.165 -115.891 7.3 BAJA CALIFORNIA, MEXICO'] ]

fixed_split = 5
b = [[' '.join(i[0].split()[:fixed_split]), ' '.join(i[0].split()[fixed_split:])] for i in a]
print(b)
```

output

```
[['2006/10/18 21:15:51 4.823 -82.592 37.3', 'SOUTH OF PANAMA'], ['2006/10/18 10:08:45 32.165 -115.891 7.3', 'BAJA CALIFORNIA, MEXICO']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.split`:

```
import re
s = [['2006/10/18 21:15:51 4.823 -82.592 37.3 SOUTH OF PANAMA']  , ['2006/10/18 10:08:45 32.165 -115.891 7.3 BAJA CALIFORNIA, MEXICO']]
new_s = [re.split('(?<=\d)\s(?=[A-Z])', i) for [i] in s]
```

Output:

```
[['2006/10/18 21:15:51 4.823 -82.592 37.3', 'SOUTH OF PANAMA'], ['2006/10/18 10:08:45 32.165 -115.891 7.3', 'BAJA CALIFORNIA, MEXICO']]
```

Answer (score 2):

`re.split()` is good choice for complex spliting:

```
import re

[re.split('([\d\/\.\-\:\s]+)\s+([A-Z\s\,]+)', x[0])[1:3] for x in a]
```